# AndEngine, how to get the width of a sprite on runtime?

Tags: andengine

I have a sprite for a png file. ( Dimensions of the png file is 432x10 ). The png file is in drawable-xxhdpi folder. When i run on emulator with hdpi density mySprite.getWidth() returns 432. ( mySprite.getWidthScaled() also returns 432.) But the png file is looked just about 200 pixel width. Which method gives right value. ( not the width of the png file.) The value that how many pixel the png file is monitorized in?   Thank you very much.

Note : My English is insufficient, sorry.

Comment: what are your camera dimensions you set?  It doesnt matter what actual screen size of your phone is (taking in account your resolution policy). For example if your phone has screen size 1080x786 and you set the camera size 800x600 and you will try to put sprite with dimmensions 800x600 it will take full screen (that is actually 1080x786).

Answer (score 0):

```
    `public Engine onLoadEngine () {      
  ....    
  SCR_WIDTH = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;    
  SCR_HEIGHT = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;    
  MyCamera = new Camera (0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);    
  ......        
}`
```